# detect aspx website by google

Tags: asp.net

Is there grammar that using google to search for the website build by asp.net. It's like searching the webpages that end with aspx(*.aspx).

Thanks!

Comment: How is this question programming related?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this search term:

```
filetype:aspx
```

This will not find sites using URL rewriting (including MVC sites).